# Regular expression to parse the command output

Tags: regex, perl

I have created a function to parse the output of a command.

The output of the command will be the following :

```
 Host-profile-count   User       114
```

( Note: the  number 114  is not constant.it could be any positive number >= 0 )

Now i just need the number ( in this case 114)  to be returned.
I guess the regex in my script is wrong. When i run the script i get the output as 0. It should be 114.
Can somebody help me out with the regex please ?

```
sub _count {

   my ($self) = @_;
   my  $cmd   = 'command goes here ';
   my  $profiles = 0;

   $self->execute($cmd);

  foreach my $line ( @{ $self->get_stdout() } ) {
       if ( $line =~ m/Host\sprofile\scount\s+\S*\s+(\S*)/msx ) {
            $profiles = $1;
        }
    }

    $profiles =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//msxg;
    return $profiles;
}
```

Comment: Change the `\s`s between the words to hyphens and it works. You also don't need any of those modifiers.

Comment: Unless you need to check for the presence of `Host-profile-count` (which is probably better done separately anyway) I would go for just `my ($profiles) = $line =~ /(\d+)/` which finds the first sequence of digits and assigns it to `$profiles`. And you shouldn't ritually add `/msx` to every regex you write -- it wastes the time of puzzled readers of your code who try to fathom why they are there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, you wronly placed `\s` (*which matches any space character*) instead of hyphen..

```
m/Host-profile-count\s+\S*\s+(\S*)/msx
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lY7kK0/1)

Add a word boundary `\b` (*which matches between a word character and a non-word character*) before `Host` if necessary.

Comment: boundary \b ? .can you please explain it to me why that is required?

Comment: without `\b` , the above regex would find a match also in `foobarHost-profile-count   User       114 ` . `\bHost-profile-count\s+\S*\s+(\S*)` won't do like the above.

Comment: since you're new to StackOverflow, i suggest you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)